# How to end the program (Python)?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, terminate

I'm a newbie in Python3 coding and I have a problem here.
In line 14, I intended to end this program by printing "Thank you! Goodbye" at the part where you answer "n" to "try again?". However, it turned out that I would start all over again even if I've inserted "break" under it. Now, the only solution I can come up is to end the whole program with `sys.exit(0)`, but I don't consider it an ideal solution since it just closes the whole program down.

```
import sys
while True:

x=int(input("Enter the coins you expected="))
f=int(input("Enter first coin="))

while f!=1 and f!=5 and f!=10 and f!=25:
   print("invalid number")
   f=int(input("Enter first coin="))

if x>f:
    while x>f:
        n=input("Enter next coin=")
        if not n:
            print("Sorry-you only entered",f,"cents")
            again=input("Try again (y/n)?=")
            if again=="y":
                True
            elif again=="n":
                print("Thank you, goodbye!")
                sys.exit(0)
            break

        while int(n)!=1 and int(n)!=5 and int(n)!=10 and int(n)!=25:
            print("invalid number")
            n=input("Enter next coin=")
        f=f+int(n)
```

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: yes, my question is answered and it worked :)!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your whole code with this:

```
import sys

Stay = True

while Stay:

    x = int(input("Enter the coins you expected = "))
    f = int(input("Enter first coin = "))

    while f != 1 and f != 5 and f != 10 and f != 25:
        f = int(input("Invalid number entered./nEnter first coin = "))

    while x > f and Stay:

        n = input("Enter next coin = ")

        if not n:

            print("Sorry, you only entered " + str(f) + " cents")
            again = input("Try again (y/n)?=")

            if again == "n":
                print("Thank you, goodbye!")
                Stay = False

        if Stay:

            n = int(n)
            while n != 1 and n != 5 and n != 10 and n != 25:
                print("Invalid number entered.")
                n = int(input("Enter next coin = "))
            f += n
```

I made your code more readable and fixed your problem by using a Boolean flag (`Stay`). This basically means that the program runs while `Stay` is `True`, and `Stay` becomes `False` when the user enters `'n'`.